# How to make a Mac mini and MacBook Pro work together (one keyboard for two Macs)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mac-mini

I have one MacBook Pro and two monitors (One monitor and one TV. Both of them are connected to my MacBook Pro).

I use this MacBook for business and development work. I would like to simultaneously use this MacBook for development work and one Mac mini I do not have yet for business work.

I want to be able to use the keyboard + Trackpad of my MacBook Pro for my MacBook and my Mac mini. I also want to display the Mac mini output on one of my two monitors (not on the built-in MacBook Pro display).

Any idea how I could set this up?

Comment: to Nixem and bdecaf 

Thanks for your answers. I upvoted both of them as they are potential solutions to my question but can't accept both of them as the answer to my question.

Comment: this question is not related to your question. Just wondering, whether you have ever connected from Mac Mini to Macbook laptop and worked from Macbook to access the Mac Mini .. something like remote login.. if so , can you please share the details..

Comment: I also vote for remote login / screen sharing

Answer (score 3):

Synergy is amazing! You can check it out at http://synergy-foss.org/ it's pretty great software! I use it in my office to use one Keyboard and Mouse for a bunch of machines I have. Even works between OSX, Linux and PCs.

Check out the site... http://synergy-foss.org/ It is a free download! It's pretty awesome stuff. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something like [teleport or alike](http://alternativeto.net/software/teleport/).

Comment: Tried it long time ago. But does not work. Using Sharemouse now. Free version. Quite happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case where I need to work concurrently on a MacBook Pro and a Mac mini. I like to have the convenience of using the MacBook Pro's built-in keyboard to control both the MacBook as well as the Mac mini. I leverage [Screen Sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac) feature built into macOS. Here's how can set it up:

Both the MacBook Pro and the Mac mini needs to be connected to the same network. On the Mac mini, go to System Preference → Sharing and turn on Screen Sharing.

[image]

Now, on your MacBook Pro, under Network, you should be able to locate the Mac mini with the name set for **Computer Name:** as shown above. Click on Share Screen.. and you should be able to see you Mac mini's screen in a window.

[image]

Move the window to one of the external monitors and make it go full screen. This way, you can have a seamless experience switching between your MacBook and Mac mini while using a single keyboard and Trackpad.

Comment: Hi Nimesh! I wanted to try your solution but I am stuck. Are you referring to the Network preference pane when talking about "under Network"? If so I couldn't locate the Mac mini.

Comment: @politicus I am not referring to the Network preference pane, but Network item in Finder. Open a new Finder window and use the keyboard shortcut Command + Shift + C. This will take you to the top-most level which will show all the connected drives and the Network item.

Comment: Thanks Nimesh! I could make it work. But I need to turn my Mac Mini firewall off.  How should I modify my Mac Mini firewall settings to not have to turn my firewall off?